# Saving all variables using loop and localStorage [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, save

I wanted to make a code that will easily save all variables. Normally i would need for 60 variables about 120 lines. Not very efficient. I decided to try to make one function with array to try to save all variables. It doesnt seem to work.

My problem is that loaded variables are string, but i need them to be float.

```
var variablelist = ["numb1","numb2","numb3","numb4","numb5"];
var variablelength = variablelist.length;

function save(){
  for (var i = 0; i < variablelength; i++){
    localStorage[variablelist[i]] = window[variablelist[i]];
  }
}

function load(){
  for (var i = 0; i < variablelength; i++){
    window[variablelist[i]] = localStorage[variablelist[i]];
  }
}
```

I have tried

```
window[variablelist[i]] = localStorage[parseFloat(variablelist[i])];
```

Nothing has worked. It is still a string. Any ideas ?

Comment: localStorage stores everything as a string, you should try `parseFloat(localStorage.getItem(variablelist[i]));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`localStore.setItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) and [`localStore.getItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) to store and load items. Also use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` to convert objects to text, and then restore them back to objects.

```
var variablelist = ["numb1","numb2","numb3","numb4","numb5"];
var variablelength = variablelist.length;

function save(){
  for (var i = 0; i < variablelength; i++){
    localStorage.setItem(variablelist[i], JSON.stringify(window[variablelist[i]]));
  }
}

function load(){
  for (var i = 0; i < variablelength; i++){
    window[variablelist[i]] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(variablelist[i]));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. I have learned a new way of transforming data JSON.parse etc.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it hurts me to see so much stuff stored on the window object like that. You should really give that a re-think!

[LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) is a way of storing a key-value pair to the browsers memory for access later. The only catch is that the value has to be a string.

You can get around this my using the `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` function:

```
var objectToSave = {
  key1: 'something',
  key2: 'something else'
};

localStorage.setItem('myObject', JSON.stringify(objectToSave));

console.log(localStorage.getItem('myObject')); // What is stored
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myObject'))); // The parsed object
```

Otherwise, if you are set on saving all of the individual variables, you are not far off, you just need to use the `getItem` and `setItem`:

```
var variablelist = ["numb1","numb2","numb3","numb4","numb5"];
var variablelength = variablelist.length;

function save(){
  for (var i = 0; i < variablelength; i++){
    localStorage.setItem(variablelist[i], window[variablelist[i]]);
  }
}

function load(){
  for (var i = 0; i < variablelength; i++){
    window[variablelist[i]] = localStorage.getItem(variablelist[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help, i forgot about getItem and setItem command. Im still learning. I found both of answers useful. Thank you again

Comment: @killereks No problem, happy to help :)